# Does having more HTML elements take up memory that could otherwise be used by the browser for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

In other words, does my internet browser's rendering engine share the same memory as the JavaScript engine? I ask because I wonder if having more HTML elements could possibly interfere with the execution of JavaScript.

Comment: What is your browser? The answer is probably no regardless though.

Comment: Chrome, but I use all mainstream browsers

Comment: Questions which ask if "x" number of variables will overflow memory are usually answered with a resounding "no". 500 million 16-bit integers take up 1 gigabyte. Random Access Memory performs just as fast full as it does empty. Under what context are you asking this question?

Comment: I am animating a group of html elements individually but at the same time. I notice that when there are more elements, the animation tends to become choppier.

Comment: That would be less of a memory issue and more of a speed issue with the code. It would make sense that it's slower the more elements you animate.

Comment: The way you write your code makes **a lot** of difference in eliminating janks in animation. For example, if you force the renderer to do lots of relayout, it's going to take a toll on performance, this can be easily triggered by reading and writing DOM variables in the wrong order. Whether you let CSS to animate or write your own code, whether you use requestAnimationFrame, whether your code ends up being GPU accelerated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and No. Everything uses the same cpu in the long run. Images consume cpu, etc. When it comes to HTML, the more the crazier, ive had games with tables of 2000x2000 and then some and been fine with javascript.